# Tranlsated Node is showing in the defaiult language

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I have a multilanguage site with its content translated.
I have a problem with some nodes which although the are translated they are showing only the default language.

For example:

- http://theacropolismuseum.gr/node/815
- http://theacropolismuseum.gr/en/node/815

They both shows the Greek translation.

On the other hand these two nodes below are correct:

- http://theacropolismuseum.gr/en/node/154
- http://theacropolismuseum.gr/node/154

  The difference between these two pairs is that the first pair contains custom paragraph, but I think I have configure them correctly for translation.

Comment: Similar issue.
Followed docs at https://www.drupal.org/node/2735121
One thing I noticed is that if I ignore the docs (and the "unspported" warnings in Drupal and check the box next to my Paragraph fields in the Content Type (not in the paragraph) it seems to work ... but I guess that's not the way to go

Comment: Checking the box "user may translate this field" in the content type does not seem to to solve the issue i can see that the translation is saved in the administration of the site  but i cannot see the translated page on my site. Is there another workaround?